# nested array of object remove specific elementin mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my data I want to remove this specific object only:
thanks to advance how to remove the specific object from a nested array element

{
"_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a6"),
"answer" : "Item Question 1 - Answer 1",
"isCorrectAnswer" : true
}

Input data:

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5397e4b75c4c9bf0509709ab"),
        "name" : "Item Name",
        "description" : "Item Description",
        "questions" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a5"),
                "question" : "Item Question 1",
                "answers" : [
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a6"),
                            "answer" : "Item Question 1 - Answer 1",
                            "isCorrectAnswer" : true
                        },
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a7"),
                            "answer" : "Item Question 1 - Answer 2",
                            "isCorrectAnswer" : false
                        }
                    
                    ]
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a9"),
                "question" : "Item Question 2",
                "answers" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5aa"),
                        "answer" : "Item Question 2 - Answer 1",
                        "isCorrectAnswer" : false
                    },
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5ab")
                        "answer" : "Item Question 2 - Answer 2",
                        "isCorrectAnswer" : true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

expected output:
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5397e4b75c4c9bf0509709ab"),
        "name" : "Item Name",
        "description" : "Item Description",
        "questions" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a5"),
                "question" : "Item Question 1",
                "answers" : [
                       
                        {
                            "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a7"),
                            "answer" : "Item Question 1 - Answer 2",
                            "isCorrectAnswer" : false
                        }
                    ]
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a9"),
                "question" : "Item Question 2",
                "answers" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5aa"),
                        "answer" : "Item Question 2 - Answer 1",
                        "isCorrectAnswer" : false
                    },
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5ab")
                        "answer" : "Item Question 2 - Answer 2",
                        "isCorrectAnswer" : true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

thanks to advance how to remove the specific object from a nested array element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solution in Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cpf0oSX_29l). Try this:

```js
db.collection.updateOne(
    { "_id": ObjectId("5397e4b75c4c9bf0509709ab") },
    {
        $pull: {
            "questions.$[].answers": {
                "_id": ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a6")
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5397e4b75c4c9bf0509709ab"),
    "name" : "Item Name",
    "description" : "Item Description",
    "questions" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a5"),
            "question" : "Item Question 1",
            "answers" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a7"),
                    "answer" : "Item Question 1 - Answer 2",
                    "isCorrectAnswer" : false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5a9"),
            "question" : "Item Question 2",
            "answers" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5aa"),
                    "answer" : "Item Question 2 - Answer 1",
                    "isCorrectAnswer" : false
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5397eb925d2664177b0fc5ab"),
                    "answer" : "Item Question 2 - Answer 2",
                    "isCorrectAnswer" : true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: its removed those questions array

Comment: No pal its working for me. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Check this in Mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/cpf0oSX_29l